# Unit testing components Vitest, Vue Test Utils, Pinia

Tags: vuejs3, vue-test-utils, pinia, vitest

```
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'

// Import component
import NavBar from '../base/layout/NavBar.vue'

const wrapper = mount(NavBar, {
  plugins: [
    createTestingPinia({
      stubActions: false,
    }),
  ],
})

describe('NavBar Test', () => {
  it('it should render', () => {
    // Find Logo
    expect(wrapper.find('.nav-logo').exists()).toBeTruthy()
    // // Find Links
    expect(wrapper.find('.nav-links').exists()).toBeTruthy()
    // // Find Toggle
    expect(wrapper.find('.nav-toggles').exists()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Creating a unit tests for a navbar component that has a simple pinia store, running into an issue where I get the following:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getNavState')`

inside the component I do the following in areas to show an open class etc

`<a href="/" class="nav-logo" :class="{ open: navStore.getNavState }">`

I've read through several sources and used the main pinia/vitest doc but can't seem to see why my store is not available (getters should work) so the test is failing

Reading through I should not need to mock a store as it should automatically work setting `stubActions` but am I wrong? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Note sure how you code for **navStore**, I guess you don't have default value while initialization state for store, So add more **initialState** in **createTestingPinia**'s option. E.g.:

```
const wrapper = mount(NavBar, {
  global: {
    plugins: [
      createTestingPinia({
        stubActions: false,
        initialState: {
          navStore: { // your store's props  },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I switched to using the following packing:

https://github.com/danielroe/nuxt-vitest

This helps test code that needs a Nuxt runtime environment

Then inside the test use the following:

```
// @vitest-environment nuxt
import { test } from 'vitest'

test('my test', () => {
  // ... test with Nuxt environment!
})
```

For my example:

```
// @vitest-environment nuxt
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'

// Import component
import NavBar from '../base/layout/NavBar.vue'

describe('NavBar Test', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(NavBar, {
    plugins: [
      createTestingPinia({
        stubActions: false,
      }),
    ],
  })

  it('it should render', () => {
    // Find Logo
    expect(wrapper.find('.nav-logo').exists()).toBeTruthy()
    // // Find Links
    expect(wrapper.find('.nav-links').exists()).toBeTruthy()
    // // Find Toggle
    expect(wrapper.find('.nav-toggle').exists()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```